# Safe place online for children to play against others

Tags: learning

I'm looking for a safe website where my child can play. He is developing his game, I'm worried about people he may meet on various websites.

If there are some known places please advise.

Comment: While there are definitely sites for kids, most regular chess sites are perfectly "safe"

Comment: @David: How could you possibly ensure that claim is true? Any site that permits communication between users (either public or private) enables relationships to develop between strangers, and therefore could be of danger to children. Sure, you are probably right that *most* chess players are going to be harmless, but you cannot claim that *all* chess players definitely are. That isn't to say you shouldn't let kids use these sites, just be sure to monitor and educate them appropriately.

Comment: @musefan There is no such thing as a 100% safe site, but chess sites aren't filled with predators just because chat is enabled (and you can disable it in all of them anyway)

Answer (score 9):

The free online chess site [**Lichess**](https://lichess.org/) offers a feature called "kid mode".
I haven't tried it out myself, but when enabled, all site communication features are disabled while the rest of the site remains functional.

It's password protected and can be enabled under [Preferences → Kid Mode](https://lichess.org/account/kid):

[image: Sample image of preferences page]

Comment: +1 I would recommend Lichess over any free site.

Comment: I would say "over any other free site". *You* know Lichess is also free, but readers of this question may not, and as written it sounds like you are implying it is not free.

Comment: I updated the answer to avoid that ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

[ChessKid](https://www.chesskid.com/) is a platform designed for kids, built by the people from chess.com.  I don't have any personal experience with this platform, though.